# Given an ElementHandle, how to find the HTML ID associated with it

Tags: node.js, playwright

In Playwright, given a valid ElementHandle object, how do I find the associated HTML ID that is associated with that element?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly: do you want the **id attribute** of an element handle?

Comment: Yes that's exactly want I mean. Given handles I obtained from `page.$$(...)` how do I get the "id" attribute of the handles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could retrieve it with `page.evaluate` like this:

```js
const elemHandle = await page.$('h1')

const idAttr = await page.evaluate(el => el.id, elemHandle)
console.log(idAttr)
```

Of course, it is not guaranteed that any element will have an `id`.

---

(*Note:* I am not aware of if the following approach is possible in Playwright as well but it works in [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/) for sure.)

If you are not restricted to id attributes you can retrieve the unique selectors of an element within the page like:

```js
console.log(elemHandle._remoteObject)
```

```
{
  type: 'object',
  subtype: 'node',
  className: 'HTMLHeadingElement',
  description: 'h1.fs-headline1.ow-break-word.mb8.flex--item.fl1',
  objectId: '5611379091209172520.3.2'
}
```

Where the value of `description` is a valid selector.

Comment: `await page.evaluate(el => el.id, elemHandle)` works great to get the `id`. The `_remoteObject` does not seem to work in Playwright.

Comment: `evaluate` works well but there is also another way.  
You can use `getProperty` method instead.  

Get property `id` using
`const elementPropId = await element.getProperty("id")`.  

Then, access it's value using 
`const elementId = await elementPropId.jsonValue()`.  

`elementId` will contain the `id`.  

For `class` you can use `await element.getProperty("className")`.   

[Currently using Puppeteer v10.4.0]